# A homework template command has a specific font. How do I change it to the default?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have been using [this homework template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/math-assignment-template/szrjcggjrxvm) for my homerwork, but the commands `\begin{question}` and `\begin{My Answer}` set a specific font to the text that I don't like. How do I change it? It has the `fontspec` package, but deleting it didn't change the font.
[image: example of the font]

Edit: forgot to show the code that lead to the text seen in the picture. Here it is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=4.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,amscd}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{shadethm}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{answer_color}{HTML}{F7F8E0}
\newshadetheorem{question}{Questão}
\declaretheorem{Resposta}
\declaretheorem{True Answer}
% \begin{question} \end{questsion}
% \begin{My Answer} \end{My Answer}
% \begin{True Answer} \end{True Answer]

\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  linkbordercolor={0 0 1}
}
 
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Algoritmo}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Algoritmos}
\def\lstlistingautorefname{Alg.}

\lstdefinestyle{Python}{
    language        = Python,
    frame           = lines, 
    basicstyle      = \footnotesize,
    keywordstyle    = \color{blue},
    stringstyle     = \color{green},
    commentstyle    = \color{red}\ttfamily
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0.0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.05in}

% Edit these as appropriate
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\lVert#1\right\rVert}
\newcommand\course{Course name}
\newcommand\Informationa{ID}
%\newcommand\Informationb{John Smith/12345678}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\headheight 35pt
\lhead{\course \\ ID: \Informationa}
%\lhead{\course \\ Name and ID: \Informationa \\ Name and ID: \Informationb}

\chead{\textbf{\Large Desafio VII}}
\lfoot{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\cfoot{\small\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\headsep 1.2em

\begin{document}
\begin{question}
Vocês verão no futuro como um processo físico, e.g. uma colisão, pode ser descrita na teoria
moderna de teoria quântica de campos. Nessa descrição, qualquer interação fundamental é descrita
pela troca de partéculas e o alcance da força é determinado pela massa da partícula mediadora.
Por exemplo, no eletromagnetismo, como o fóton é uma partícula sem massa, a interação tem um
alcance infinito, enquanto que a interação fraca, por exemplo, tem um alcance pequeno ja que é
intermediada por bósons massivos chamados W e Z.
Hideki Yukawa, é famoso por ter introduzido um potencial análogo ao de Coulomb levando em
conta essa limitação de alcance devido à massa do mediador. O potencial, denominado potencial
de Yukawa, tem a forma
\end{question}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show a short compilable TeX code resulting in your screenshot?

Comment: @Mensch Thank you! Yes, sorry, I forgot abou that. Will edit it.